# Findstr not functioning properly when searching for numbers

Tags: windows, batch

```
findstr /rb /s "[2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>" %userprofile%\*.txt >>output.txt
```

The purpose of this code is to search for a string in all of %userprofile%, a string that is 16 numbers long and starts with the number 2, then write that in output.txt

At the desktop, I have made a file called test.txt which contains the following numbers, and nothing else: 2123456789123456

The program containing the findstr command is found in the %userprofile% directory.

However, when I run the program, the output.txt file comes out blank.

EDIT: Does someone have an idea as to where the error might be?

Answer (score 3):

I've documented many confounding FINDSTR features and bugs at [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053)

There are two issues in your code that lead to failure.

**1) FINDSTR regex is limited to a maximum of 15 [class] terms**

Your search has 16, so it cannot work. But your first term is `[2]`, which could be simplified to `2`. So the following ***should*** work:

```
findstr /rb /s "2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>" "%userprofile%\*.txt" >>output.txt
```

But it does not, as evidenced by

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /rb "2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"

>
```

returns nothing.

I believe this exposes a previously unknown bug or *"feature"* :-/

I haven't had time to thoroughly investigate, but the proposed bug/feature is:

**2) The begin word anchor `\<` and end word anchor `\>` both count toward the `[class]` term limit of 15. The search can fail silently if the search includes either anchor, and the cumulative term count is exactly 16** (Proposed new bug report - partially tested on Win 10 only)

The `\>` end word anchor should match the point before a non word character, or end of line, or end of input. But in my test case above, there are 15 class terms, plus one end of word anchor, making a total of 16, which fails silently.

If I change the test to:

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /rb "21[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"
2123456789123456

>
```

Then the total count is 15, and it finds the number.

Similarly, the `\<` word begin anchor should match the beginning of input, beginning of line, or the position immediately after a "non-word" character.

But the test below has a cumulative term count of 16, which also fails silently:

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /r "\<2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

>
```

If I eliminate one of the class terms, then the count is 15, and it succeeds:

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /r "\<21[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
2123456789123456

>
```

If I include both anchors with the 15 class terms, then the total count is 17, and I get the `FINDSTR: Search string too long.` error.

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /r "\<2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"
FINDSTR: Search string too long.

>
```

If I remove one class term, then the total term count is 16, and it fails silently:

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /r "\<21[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"

>
```

If I remove another class term, then the total term count is 15, and it works

```
>echo 2123456789123456|findstr /r "\<212[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"
2123456789123456

>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### When I run the program, the output.txt file comes out blank

> Does someone have an idea as to where the error might be?

Your search string is too long.

Demonstration:

```
> echo 2123456789123456 | findstr /rb "[2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\>"
FINDSTR: Search string too long.

> echo 2123456789123456 | findstr /rb "[2][0-9]*\>"
2123456789123456
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman)

Comment: To be more precise, there are too many square bracket class terms - FINDSTR is limited to a maximum of 15. But there seems to be another issue at play.

Comment: @dbenham Hmm. I looked in your wonderful q/a and didn't see that limitation there. Why do you think there is another issue?

Comment: So I would have to use something like VBScript to search for a string that is 16 numbers in length?

Comment: @Daniel Or powershell. Or a bash script ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - See my [new answer](https://superuser.com/a/1202013/109090). This question has led to the discovery of a new "feature"

Comment: @DavidPostill - Also, I'm assuming you are now on Win 10 like me. Older versions gave a different message when the `[class]` term limit of 15 is exceeded. But Win 10 behavior seems to have changed such that the error message is the same as if the total search string is longer than 511 characters.

Comment: @dbenham I'm still on Windows 7 :)

Comment: Doh. So am I. LOL I'm at home, where I use Win 10, but I forgot I am working remotely on Win 7. It is hard to keep track of the subtle FINDSTR differences between versions. The error messages are one type of difference.